# Kubernetes - Update deployment with custom change cause

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to k8s. I want to specify my own change cause with rollouts. I know I can use the --record:

```
kubectl set image deployment/tomcat-deployment tomcat=tomcat:9.0.1 --record
```

But I'd like to specify my own change cause (e.g. "Update to Tomcat 9.0.1"

I tried this:

`kubectl annotate deployment tomcat-deployment kubernetes.io/change-cause='Tomcat9.0.1`'

but it changes the change cause the whole kubectl annotate command above

is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no K8s tool to help you do this. If you want to add annotations to keep the track of what you are doing to can do it through patches as follows:

```
kubectl patch RESOURCE RESOURCE_NAME  --patch '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"my-annotation-key": "my-annotation-value"}}}'
```

So, if you would want to add an annotation to a deployment, you would do:

```
kubectl patch deployment tomcat-deployment --patch '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"tomcat-deployment kubernetes.io/change-cause": "Tomcat9.0.1"}}}'
```

Now, I don't think this is a good approach. I personally would never do this. The best way may be would be to have a CI/CD implemented (jenkins, ansible) and keep the track through commits.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For our own apps we will definitely use CI/CD, but I wanted a way to do it for other containers from 3rd parties

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `kubectl patch` command above does exactly the same thing as the `kubectl annotate` command mentioned in the original post. The `kubectl annotate` command will set the change cause to the value of the annotation (at least with Kubernetes 1.14/1.15).